# Identify this Transformer with wings and tank treads / caterpillar tracks

Tags: character-identification, transformers

Who is this?

[image: Unknown Transformer]

I originally saw this in a [Transformers Colouring Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1974090612)<sup>1</sup> but I cannot identify him. He apparently has caterpillar tracks on his arms, so I'm guessing he changes into a tank. And it looks like he has wings on his legs.

I'm pretty sure he is not one of the many incarnations of these jet / tank characters:

- [Blitzwing](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Blitzwing)
- [Grand Slam](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Grand_Slam) - though this is [quite close](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/86/ed/05/86ed05e72f3ec7132fa0b92c7ce5ec11.jpg)
- [Flywheels](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Flywheels)
- [Overlord](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Overlord_(Masterforce))

This image does not show any allegiance badge so we cannot see if he is an Autobot or a Decepticon.

So who is it?

<sub>1 Unfortunately this book contained Transformers from multiple universes so I could not easily identify this one.</sub>

Comment: Reverse searching the image on google tells me it's Hound but it doesn't look quite right

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - yeah, I tried that. I think Google Image search got this one wrong.

Comment: Blitzwing is also quite similar (though I see you've already mentioned him and he doesn't quite match anyway). I've come across this image in a few places now too but nowhere does it give a name to the transformer.

Comment: Do you know what the colouring book was for? Movies? Comics? Games? etc.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The colouring book was a mixture of Transformer universes - that's why this is so hard to identify. I will update the question, thanks.

Comment: Assuming they cared about the modes, he has no tank treads anywhere but on the arms, so the legs probably fold up on top of him. Which would seem to imply he will move backwards unless the intent is forward swept wings...

Comment: fwiw - the linked book does not appear to be officially licensed - since there is no affiliation shown on this character, is it reasonable to assume that he may be a third-party creation and not 'real' at all?

Comment: There also doesn't appear to be any sort of canon visible, so I'm not sold on him being a tank. The art looks very IDW-like. They change designs, but they're usually pretty good about robot/alt-modes making sense.

Comment: Honestly, a lot of the related images look like someone has made them up, especially the one in question.

Comment: @Möoz - I don't think so. I really think I've seen this before. Although the fact that he doesn't have a badge does back up your theory.

Comment: @Wikis: And some of them didn't have the badge in the front. Sixshot, for example, has it I think towards his back, possibly reflecting his status as being more of a free agent.

Comment: Thanks for [the extra research](https://www.reddit.com/r/transformers/comments/85kexk/trying_to_identify_this_bot_from_a_tf_coloring/) @phantom42!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a piece of fanart by Hervé Creach, [posted to his DeviantArt account](https://jet2022.deviantart.com/art/War-Within-Springer-personal-Design-314091872). It is meant to be the character [Springer](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Springer_(G1)), as he would appear in the [War Within](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/War_Within_(comic)) setting. However, Creach's design differs significantly from the design for Springer seen in the actual War Within comics, such as here on the cover of *The War Within: [The Dark Ages issue #2](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Escalation)*:

[image]
[image]

Given that this is not official art, and that the coloring book containing the image was released through Amazon's CreateSpace print-on-demand publishing platform, it seems likely that the coloring book is an unlicensed publication, potentially violating the copyrights of the artists whose work is included in it as well as Hasbro's trademarks relating to the Transformers intellectual property.

Comment: nice! exactly what I suggested in comments a couple of months ago, had but no evidence to support.

Comment: Wow! How did you find that?

Comment: @Wikis Google reverse image search!

Comment: Weird that it worked for you but not for me (nor apparently anyone else). I tried for ages. Congrats!

Comment: @Wikis Well, you gotta comb through the results that are obviously contextless reposts until one seems distinctive.

Answer (score 7):

After searching for items on the Transformer wiki that included mention of tank treads, I think there's a possibility this is supposed to be [Sixshot](http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Sixshot).

[image: Sixshot toy] [image: Sixshot in the cartoon]

On the toy, you can see the tank treads on the arms, as well as wings on the legs and arms. The general shape of the head and body is right. As regards the other bits not fitting, the toy had a lot of detachable "kibble" to justify the six different forms.

> Few Decepticons are as feared as Sixshot (aka Six Shot), either by the Autobots or by their own comrades. As the first Transformer Six Changer, able to assume six different modes, he is officially designated as a "Solo Transformer Assault Group" (or "S.T.A.G."), but is more colloquially known among those who know and fear him as a "one-robot army". Sixshot's destructive ability is the stuff of legend, a gleeful murderousness that is matched in ferocity only by the intensity with which he sets to the bloody tasks given him. He is not to be mistaken for a mindless weapon, however—he is highly intelligent, and not without honor of a warped sort. He grants due respect to any opponent he deems worthy, and always speaks well of them after he has inevitably dispatched them to, as he puts it, "the great junkyard in the sky".
>
> These attitudes are reflective of Sixshot's understanding of the inevitable end that waits for a warrior such as he, and the hope that when his own end eventually arrives he will be remembered in the same way. But that end will be long in coming, for although Sixshot believes that life is only worth living for as long as there are opponents who can challenge him, his mantra does not preclude his own allegiance changing in order to make new enemies and challenges where none existed before.

Comment: I don't buy it - one of the defining features of Sixshot appear to be the large vertical fins on his back which are absent from the drawing

Comment: Weeeell, it matches the "tank/jet" idea. But otherwise it doesn't seem close enough. I suspect the image I posted is from the box art - and the [Sixshot box art](http://www.transformerland.com/store/inventory/170330/IMG_1366.JPG) doesn't seem to match.

Comment: ^_^ Eh, it's the best match I've found so far. Which isn't saying too much.

Comment: I think this question appears deceptively simple... :D

Comment: FuzzyBoots (aka Fuzzy Boots). It's amazing the difference one empty character can make.

Comment: Yeah, good find, but I think his shoulder pads don't match.